# Compare only the latest Records

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger that updates new records to a second table if it meets a condition

```
TableA

#ID,animalid,calvdate,lactation
1,animal1, 2016-03-15,1
2,animal1, 2017-06-09,2

TableB
#animalid, calvdate, milkmorning, milkevening
animal1,2017-07-09,2,2
animal1,2018-08-27,3,3
```

I want to update the new correct calvdate to table. Below is my query

```
SELECT animalid,calvdate,lactation FROM tableB
inner join tableA on tableB.animalid = tableA.animalid
where TO_DAYS(tableA.calvdate) -TO_DAYS(tableB.calvdate) > 400
group by animalid and calvdate

Expected Output 

  #ID,animalid,calvdate,lactation
    1,animal1, 2016-03-15,1
    2,animal1, 2017-06-09,2
    3,animal1, 2018-08-27,3
```

NOTE:lactation has to be automatically generated

the expected output has three records, because the new calvdate meets the condition when compared to the last calvdate and is greater than 400 days

Comment: Please explain better the logic by which you arrive at 3 records in the output.

Comment: the expected output has three because the new calvdate meets the condition when compared to the last calvdate @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed few things here.

1.Lactation will increment for each animal ID separately.
2.Need to only compare with the latest calvdate in each animal ID and insert records from B if the difference is greater than 400 days.

```
<insert into A>
SELECT B.animalid,B.calvdate,init.lactation
FROM 
(SELECT MAX(calvdate) as calvdate, animalid FROM tableB GROUP BY animalid) B
left join 
(SELECT MAX(calvdate) as calvdate, MAX(lactation) + 1 as lactation, animalid FROM tableA GROUP BY animalid) init
on 
B.animalid = init.animalid
AND DATEDIFF(B.calvdate,init.calvdate) > 400
WHERE init.animalid IS NOT NULL
```

You can view a SQL server simulation of this here: https://rextester.com/BLT38001